# What is a Count Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Count Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Count Words™ | Not Count Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| GUNK | TRASH |
| TRIFLE | TOFFEE |
| ADD | SUB |
| CLIFF | VALLEY |
| GYM | LAZE |
| WOW | MEH |
| BAD | GOOD |
| FLIER | POSTER |
| EXCITE | IMPRESS |
| HAHA | LOL |
| FLIRT | CREEP |
| MUSK | MELON |
| RELIC | MONK |
| SKY | SEA |
| SUNNY | WINDY |
| FILTER | HASHTAG |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Count Words™, Not Count Words™
GUNK, TRASH
TRIFLE, TOFFEE
ADD, SUB
CLIFF, VALLEY
GYM, LAZE
WOW, MEH
BAD, GOOD
FLIER, POSTER
EXCITE, IMPRESS
HAHA, LOL
FLIRT, CREEP
MUSK, MELON
RELIC, MONK
SKY, SEA
SUNNY, WINDY
FILTER, HASHTAG
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Count Word™ or not on its own.

I shall be giving 10 hints periodically if the puzzle isn't solved soon

HINT 0

> 

HINT 1

> 

Comment: I have just started frequenting this website a couple of days ago. Wanted to ask if it's rude to post too many questions?
(This is my second question in a couple of days)

Comment: In my opinion multiples question are valid if they are elaborated and good. I saw multiple questions by the same guy but all of them horrible, old-puzzles all solved within minutes. You should discuss this in [meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/) or the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) ^^

Comment: I think posting multiple questions within a short time is ok.

Comment: Posting *bad puzzles* is bad. Posting *so many puzzles that no one else's can be seen* is bad. Other than that, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: I want to post one of these.  How do you make those charts?

Comment: @GabrielBurns: Screenshot of an Excel spreadsheet? Some of the tables in the series are made with MathJax, SE's maths markup language. But you may not need a table at all. Unless you must rely on some special visual representation you could just post the words. The layout "table image plus CSV" is iconic, but by no means necessary.

Comment: Or simply format the stuff in Excel, select all the cells and do Ctrl+C(Copy) next in the contend editor, click on Add Image and do Ctrl+V(Paste). That's all.

Comment: I use OpenOffice and take a screenshot.

Comment: Is triffle meant to be trifle? Triffle is not a word but trifle is a dessert like toffee is.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. Got confused I guess. Yup should be trifle

Comment: I am upvoting this solely because of hint 0 and hint 1. Very clever hints, indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Count Word™ is a word where

> each letter, when converted to the binary ASCII representation, has the same number of 1s (and 0s) as all the other letters in the word.
> For example `GUNK` in binary is `01000111 01010101 01001110 01001011`, but `TRASH` in binary is `01010100 01010010 01000001 01010011 01001000`.
> $$\tiny \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \text{Count Word™}&\text{Non Count Word™}\\\hline \text{01000111 01010101 01001110 01001011 }&\text{01010100 01010010 01000001 01010011 01001000 }\\\hline \text{01010100 01010010 01001001 01000110 01001100 01000101 }&\text{01010100 01001111 01000110 01000110 01000101 01000101 }\\\hline \text{01000001 01000100 01000100 }&\text{01010011 01010101 01000010 }\\\hline \text{01000011 01001100 01001001 01000110 01000110 }&\text{01010110 01000001 01001100 01001100 01000101 01011001 }\\\hline \text{01000111 01011001 01001101 }&\text{01001100 01000001 01011010 01000101 }\\\hline \text{01010111 01001111 01010111 }&\text{01001101 01000101 01001000 }\\\hline \text{01000010 01000001 01000100 }&\text{01000111 01001111 01001111 01000100 }\\\hline \text{01000110 01001100 01001001 01000101 01010010 }&\text{01010000 01001111 01010011 01010100 01000101 01010010 }\\\hline \text{01000101 01011000 01000011 01001001 01010100 01000101 }&\text{01001001 01001101 01010000 01010010 01000101 01010011 01010011 }\\\hline \text{01001000 01000001 01001000 01000001 }&\text{01001100 01001111 01001100 }\\\hline \text{01000110 01001100 01001001 01010010 01010100 }&\text{01000011 01010010 01000101 01000101 01010000 }\\\hline \text{01001101 01010101 01010011 01001011 }&\text{01001101 01000101 01001100 01001111 01001110 }\\\hline \text{01010010 01000101 01001100 01001001 01000011 }&\text{01001101 01001111 01001110 01001011 }\\\hline \text{01010011 01001011 01011001 }&\text{01010011 01000101 01000001 }\\\hline \text{01010011 01010101 01001110 01001110 01011001 }&\text{01010111 01001001 01001110 01000100 01011001 }\\\hline \text{01000110 01001001 01001100 01010100 01000101 01010010 }&\text{01001000 01000001 01010011 01001000 01010100 01000001 01000111 }\\\hline\end{array}$$